# Selenium IDE not recording for one particular web page

Tags: ide, selenium

I have been researching this for a week and have not found anyone who has had a similar problem.

Selenium IDE is not recording for a site that I was previously able to record test scripts for. I am using selenium IDE 1.6.0 and Firefox 10.

About two weeks ago I was able to record the base url and the authentication process and some minor functionality tests. Now, selenium IDE doesn't record any actions for this particular website at all. It works normally for just about any other website I have tried.

Are there restrictions to Selenium IDE and what it can record?

-Ann

Comment: Can you provide link to that webpage and some test credentials?

Comment: Mine is also not recording. However there is workaround to write your own test. Will try to help you next week, this week I am in bit work overload...

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I do know how to write my own tests- I write them in eclipse and run them via testng. However, recording would have been faster/more convenient. I wonder what is different about that website that it will not record?

Comment: It contains DHTML, so my guess is that you will have to define the elements by yourself, using XPath